# DEBUG-BSOD - wireless or the sound driver?

Tags: windows-7, bsod

There is a Dell Latitude E5500 laptop, which had a BSOD on Friday.

The *tech guy* said it's the sound. However, I used WinDbg from the WinSDK and it clearly shows that the Intel Wifi driver caused the BSOD.

Here is the debug of the dump:

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 6.12.0002.633 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.


Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Summary Dump File: Only kernel address space is available

Symbol search path is: SRV*c:\websymbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
Windows 7 Kernel Version 7601 (Service Pack 1) MP (4 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS Personal
Built by: 7601.17514.amd64fre.win7sp1_rtm.101119-1850
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`02c5d000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`02ea2e90
Debug session time: Fri Apr 15 14:42:23.215 2011 (UTC + 2:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 0:02:14.776
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
.............................................................
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
....
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

Use !analyze -v to get detailed debugging information.

BugCheck D1, {fffff88004110c00, 2, 0, fffff88005b0fe75}

*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for NETw5s64.sys
Probably caused by : NETw5s64.sys ( NETw5s64+30e75 )

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

1: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL (d1)
An attempt was made to access a pageable (or completely invalid) address at an
interrupt request level (IRQL) that is too high.  This is usually
caused by drivers using improper addresses.
If kernel debugger is available get stack backtrace.
Arguments:
Arg1: fffff88004110c00, memory referenced
Arg2: 0000000000000002, IRQL
Arg3: 0000000000000000, value 0 = read operation, 1 = write operation
Arg4: fffff88005b0fe75, address which referenced memory

Debugging Details:
------------------


READ_ADDRESS:  fffff88004110c00 

CURRENT_IRQL:  2

FAULTING_IP: 
NETw5s64+30e75
fffff880`05b0fe75 41813c2400005555 cmp     dword ptr [r12],55550000h

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  VISTA_DRIVER_FAULT

BUGCHECK_STR:  0xD1

PROCESS_NAME:  System

TRAP_FRAME:  fffff880077a2870 -- (.trap 0xfffff880077a2870)
NOTE: The trap frame does not contain all registers.
Some register values may be zeroed or incorrect.
rax=0000000000003746 rbx=0000000000000000 rcx=0000000000000001
rdx=0000000000000002 rsi=0000000000000000 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=fffff88005b0fe75 rsp=fffff880077a2a00 rbp=fffffa80053390f0
 r8=fffffa8004edf600  r9=0000000000000000 r10=fffff88003307180
r11=0000000000000002 r12=0000000000000000 r13=0000000000000000
r14=0000000000000000 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
NETw5s64+0x30e75:
fffff880`05b0fe75 41813c2400005555 cmp     dword ptr [r12],55550000h ds:09f0:0000=????????
Resetting default scope

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from fffff80002cdcbe9 to fffff80002cdd640

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff880`077a2728 fffff800`02cdcbe9 : 00000000`0000000a fffff880`04110c00 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`077a2730 fffff800`02cdb860 : fffff880`0410d008 fffffa80`053b8200 fffffa80`056fb000 00000000`00008000 : nt!KiBugCheckDispatch+0x69
fffff880`077a2870 fffff880`05b0fe75 : fffff880`0410d484 00000000`00008000 fffffa80`056009f0 00000000`00008000 : nt!KiPageFault+0x260
fffff880`077a2a00 fffff880`05b0fab8 : 00000000`14ef576a fffffa80`053b8840 00000000`14ef576a 00000000`14f0224e : NETw5s64+0x30e75
fffff880`077a2a70 fffff880`05b05dc8 : fffffa80`053b8801 fffffa80`053b8840 fffff880`077a2bff fffffa80`04d85101 : NETw5s64+0x30ab8
fffff880`077a2b00 fffff880`05d9b7e2 : fffffa80`06db0c00 fffffa80`04d851a0 fffffa80`04d851a0 fffffa80`06db0b60 : NETw5s64+0x26dc8
fffff880`077a2b70 fffff880`016e4d32 : fffff880`016b9110 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`04d851a0 fffffa80`04d85f68 : NETw5s64+0x2bc7e2
fffff880`077a2ba0 fffff880`0166994d : 00000000`00000002 00000000`0000000a 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000001 : ndis!ndisMiniportDpc+0xe2
fffff880`077a2c10 fffff880`0168ff3d : 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000002 00000000`00000000 fffffa80`0560ef08 : ndis!ndisQueuedMiniportDpcWorkItem+0xcd
fffff880`077a2cb0 fffff800`02f7acce : 00000000`11f9c04a fffffa80`06db0b60 00000000`00000080 fffffa80`06db0b60 : ndis!ndisReceiveWorkerThread+0x1bd
fffff880`077a2d40 fffff800`02ccefe6 : fffff800`02e4fe80 fffffa80`06db0b60 fffff800`02e5dcc0 fffff880`01228cb0 : nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`077a2d80 00000000`00000000 : fffff880`077a3000 fffff880`0779d000 fffff880`077a2a00 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxStartSystemThread+0x16


STACK_COMMAND:  kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
NETw5s64+30e75
fffff880`05b0fe75 41813c2400005555 cmp     dword ptr [r12],55550000h

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  NETw5s64+30e75

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: NETw5s64

IMAGE_NAME:  NETw5s64.sys

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4aafedb7

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD1_NETw5s64+30e75

BUCKET_ID:  X64_0xD1_NETw5s64+30e75

Followup: MachineOwner
---------

1: kd> lmvm NETw5s64
start             end                 module name
fffff880`05adf000 fffff880`0618c000   NETw5s64   (no symbols)           
    Loaded symbol image file: NETw5s64.sys
    Image path: \SystemRoot\system32\DRIVERS\NETw5s64.sys
    Image name: NETw5s64.sys
    Timestamp:        Tue Sep 15 21:40:39 2009 (4AAFEDB7)
    CheckSum:         006A6E93
    ImageSize:        006AD000
    Translations:     0000.04b0 0000.04e4 0409.04b0 0409.04e4
```

Any thoughts on what caused the BSOD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick [Google](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=NETw5s64) shows other people having problem with `NETw5s64.sys` - stretching back to 2009. Most issues seem to be resolved by updating the driver to the latest from Intel, not the OEM vendor.

Ignoring driver updates though, you can quickly check whether the driver is at fault or not by disabling the wireless adapter* for a period of time and seeing if the computer BSOD's.

**Yes, it's inconvenient to be without internet.*

Comment: No need to even disable the wireless driver.  The crash dump is very clear and the symbols are correct.  He's examining the correct and most recent crash dump.  There is very little chance that the issue isn't with the wireless.  Update the driver and then if the computer continues crashing you most likely have a bad wifi card.

Comment: Thank you (both of you). I have updated the wifi driver to the latest available from the Intel support center. Hope this will fix the issue for once and for all.